# SharedPreference is not working in checkbox

Tags: android

I want to fill the TextView of another activity based on preference on checkBox event but its working please help me to sort the issue..It is forcefully stopping.Please help in the if else statement part .what we need to write in activity 2 to select based on the checkBox in activity 1

Activity 1:

```
package com.example.rajatanurag.shoppingsites;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Book extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1,b2;
    public static CheckBox cb1,cb2,cb3;
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    SharedPreferences sp1;
    ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3;
    String x,y,z;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
        cb1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        cb2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb2);
        cb3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb3);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv2);
        iv3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv3);
        sp1=getSharedPreferences("SHOPPING",MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void OnClick1(View view)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp1.edit();
        if(cb1.isChecked()==true) {

            editor.putString("price1", tv1.getText().toString());
            editor.putBoolean("x",true);
        }
        if(cb2.isChecked()==true)
        {

            editor.putString("price2",tv2.getText().toString());
            editor.putBoolean("y",true);

        }
        if(cb3.isChecked()==true)
        {

            editor.putString("price3",tv3.getText().toString());
            editor.putBoolean("z",true);
        }
        editor.commit();
        Intent i=new Intent(this,MyCart.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

2.Activity

```
package com.example.rajatanurag.shoppingsites;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MyCart extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences sp1;
    TextView tv4,tv5,tv6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_cart);
        tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        sp1=getSharedPreferences("SHOPPING",MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(Book.cb1.isChecked()==true){
            String price11 = sp1.getString("price1", "");
            tv4.setText(price11);
        }
        if(Book.cb1.isChecked()==true){
            String price21=sp1.getString("price2","");
            tv5.setText(price21);
        }
        if(Book.cb1.isChecked()==true){ 
            String price31=sp1.getString("price3","");
            tv6.setText(price31);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Book.cb1` to check if that checkbox has been selected or not . Use the shared preferences that  you are updating on clicking the check box

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using static variables for view members because you might get memory leaks. Also the views you are referencing are destroyed when activity is destroyed, so they are not accessible in your second activity. You can send checkboxes checked values as intent extras.

Put this in your Activity 1 in `OnClick1()` method:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,MyCart.class);
i.putExtra("cb1", cb1.isChecked());
i.putExtra("cb2", cb2.isChecked());
i.putExtra("cb3", cb3.isChecked());
startActivity(i);
```

This is how you get values in Activity 2 (in `onCreate()` method):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.getBooleanExtra("cb1", false)){
    String price11 = sp1.getString("price1", "");
    tv4.setText(price11);
}
if(intent.getBooleanExtra("cb2", false)){
    String price21=sp1.getString("price2","");
    tv5.setText(price21);
}
if(intent.getBooleanExtra("cb3", false)){ 
    String price31=sp1.getString("price3","");
    tv6.setText(price31);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void OnClick1(View view)
 {
  if(view.getID() == R.id.cb1)
  {
    if(cb1.isChecked())
         editor.putBoolean("x",true);
     else
        editor.putBoolean("x",false);
   }
 }
```

In your second activity

```
 sp1=getSharedPreferences("SHOPPING",MODE_PRIVATE);
 boolean isChecked =  sp1.getBoolean("x", false);

 if(isChecked){
  String price11 = sp1.getString("price1", "");
  tv4.setText(price11);
  }
```